# Aggregate Function with Variable By List

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an R Script to summarize measures in a data frame. I'd like it to react dynamically to changes in the structure of the data frame. For example, I have the following block.

```
library(plyr) #loading plyr just to access baseball data frame
MyData <- baseball[,cbind("id","h")]
AggHits <- aggregate(x=MyData$h, by=list(MyData[,"id"]), FUN=sum)
```

This block creates a data frame (AggHits) with the total hits (h) for each player (id). Yay.

Suppose I want to bring in the team. How do I change the by argument so that AggHits has the total hits for each combination of "id" and "team"? I tried the following and the second line throws an error: arguments must have same length

```
MyData <- baseball[,cbind("id","team","h")]
AggHits <- aggregate(x=MyData$h, by=list(MyData[,cbind("id","team")]), FUN=sum)
```

More generally, I'd like to write the second line so that it automatically aggregates h by all variables except h. I can generate the list of variables to group by pretty easily using setdiff.

```
# set the list of variables to summarize by as everything except hits
SumOver <- setdiff(colnames(MyData),"h")

# total up all the hits - again this line throws an error
AggHits <- aggregate(x=MyData$h, by=list(MyData[,cbind(SumOver)]), FUN=sum)
```

The business purpose I'm using this for involves a csv file which has a single measure ($) and currently has about a half dozen dimensions (product, customer, state code, dates, etc.). I'd like to be able to add dimensions to the csv file without having to edit the script each time.

I should mention that I've been able to accomplish this using ddply, but I know that using ddply to summarize a single measure is wasteful in regards to run time; aggregate is much faster.

Thanks in advance!

ANSWER (specific to example in question)
Block should be

```
MyData <- baseball[,cbind("id","team","h")]
SumOver <- setdiff(colnames(MyData),"h")
AggHits <- aggregate(x=MyData$h, by=MyData[SumOver], FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This aggregates by every non-integer column (ID, Team, League), but more generically shows a strategy to aggregate over an arbitrary list of columns (`by=MyData[cols.to.group.on]`):

```
MyData <- plyr::baseball
cols <- names(MyData)[sapply(MyData, class) != "integer"]
aggregate(MyData$h, by=MyData[cols], sum)
```

Comment: You can simplify this to `aggregate(h ~ ., data = MyData[sapply(MyData, class) != "integer"], sum)`

Comment: @Ramnath, I split out the `cols` piece to make it clear you can put whatever you want in `cols`.  The actual `aggregate` statement is of similar simplicity under either approach.  I personally think the `aggregate.data.frame` version is more intuitive to people less familiar with R.

Comment: Thanks for your help gentlemen. My script is working.

Comment: @BrodieG You are right that the formula interface might be confusing to those new to R.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `aggregate` from base R

```
data(baseball, package = "plyr")

MyData  <- baseball[,c("id","h", "team")]
AggHits <- aggregate(h ~ ., data = MyData, sum)
```

Comment: This makes sense. The problem is that I have other fields in the data that I don't want to aggregate by. e.g. I have the date the service was performed and the date the invoice was paid. I want to include paid date in the summary and leave off service date...

Comment: I think I had an idea. I can just cut those other fields out from the data argument. Let me try this.

Comment: Your example works, but when I try to extend this to my business data I get an error of "no rows to aggregate". Are there certain data types that are not compatible with the dot notation?

Comment: As long as `h` is `numeric`, this should work. What are the classes of the other columns in your data frame?

Comment: It's a data content issue. One of the columns had a type issue and every single record was set to N/A.